# Offset divs in a grid layout

Tags: css, layout, grid-layout

I'm new to grid layout, and I wonder what is the best way to make things exit the grid a little bit, for a "ribbon" effect for instance :
[image]

(image from http://www.red-team-design.com/css-ribbons)

Comment: use negative margin-left

Comment: That's it ? That won't break the grid or anything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've lined up the ribbon to the grid and styled it, you'll add something like this to your CSS:

```
.ribbon {
margin-left: -10px;
}
```